# Good visual graph of forks and why github is good

Tags: github

Im writing about opensource and crowdsourcing.

Github is great because one can take a copy, change something and if its good the change can be merged back to the "original"

Im trying to find a good visual example. Im looking for a project that has been fork by one person and then this one have been forked by a second person and THEN the changed have been merged back to the original.

Does anyone know about such an example?

How would *you* like to see a graphic example of why github is amayzing? (i like the complexity of the forks of https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/network - but its too big to show in a good way)

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a *cool* visual example, the article "[Collaborative_Github_Workflow](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/Collaborative_Github_Workflow)" does detail the notion of fork:

[image: GitHub forks]

And with pull requests (1), it all goes back to the original repo:

[image: GitHub cycle]

---

Here are the branches '`next`' and '`pu`' of the [GitHub repo for Got itself](https://github.com/git/git/network):

[image: pu and next]